# Bamboo not running NUnit webdriver tests

Tags: bamboo

We have a CI setup using bamboo where one job was to run our automation, it checks out our Automation Solution from a repository, and run it using NUnit runner where it contains tests using selenium webdriver and some unit tests. It runs unit tests(not using webdriver commands) just fine, but not the webdriver tests.

We are sure that the solution is being checkout correctly because we can run the test using the command line referencing the created local repository, including tests that uses webdriver using the command below:

C:\pathToNUnitConsole\nunit-console C:\pathToCreatedLocalRepositoryInTheServer\NUnitTest.dll -include=FirefoxBrowserTest

We can see that the bamboo job never launched a browser, and we are getting test failure for not seeing browser elements. Also, we are getting error as we see in the logs:

10-Apr-2015 13:19:49    http://10.215.12.28:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=587410860
10-Apr-2015 13:20:42    JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/CertUtils.jsm, line 168: NS_ERROR_ABORT: Certificate issuer is not built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your problem, but it sounds very similar to an issue I had trying to get NUnit runner to run tests built in SpecsFor.MVC, which is a wrapper that deals with instantiating an IIS Express instance, deploying a target web application to known location, then using Selenium/Chrome Driver to run the tests against the web app.

The problem I had was trying to run the Bamboo remote agent as a windows service. The Local Service account was not able to access the interactive desktop. Also, changing the service to run as a specific user account still failed, as the service was not allowed access to the user's isolated Session0.

I could login as that test user and run the test from the command line no trouble, but I couldn't get it to run when initiated by the remote agent windows service.

I eventually fixed it by using [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) (not a plug. I'm sure other similar solutions are available). This allowed me to set the machine running the tests to always log in as the test user on startup, would automatically restart the bamboo remote agent if it was closed for some reason and most importantly, to give the service access to the user's isolated session0.

Hope that might give you a few clues...